# How to check the value of several variables in a th: text thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I find a lot of tutorial to check if a variable is null or not in a th: text.

But I can not find to check several, and change the text.

here is my example:

```
th:text="|${item?.startDate} ${item?.endDate} ${item?.startTime} ${item?.endTime}|"
```

See that sometimes one or more of its 4 variables can be null, so sometimes I have null displayed.

I therefore want to display

From XX to YY at 10 a.m. until 7 p.m.

And if possible, be able to use the locales 'From' 'To' 'to' and 'to' so that this line is multi-lingual.

Precision:

I use internalization well:

```
message1= Starts on(en), Débute le (fr)
message2=  Ends on( en), se termine le (fr)
message 3= begins to (en), commence à(fr)
message4= finishes at (en), se termine à (fr)
```

So I want to Show

```
Fr: Débute le item.startDate se termine le item.endDate commence à item.startTime se termine à item.endTime
en: Starts on item.startDate ends on item.endDate begins to item.startTime finishes at item.endTime
```

but the problem is that sometimes I have item.startTime and / or item.endTime which is / are null

So I want to display the message partially:

```
 Fr: Débute le item.startDate se termine le item.endDate 
    en: Starts on item.startDate ends on item.endDate
```

And sometimes I can have item.startTime and item.endTime not null but item.startDate and item.endDate null
So I will want to display the following message:

```
 Fr: commence à item.startTime se termine à item.endTime
    en:  begins to item.startTime finishes at item.endTime
```

I can't find the correct syntax for this example

thanking you

Comment: I am not sure what "_use the locales 'From' 'To' 'to' and 'to'_" means, exactly... But I would use Java to determine the correct values for `from` and `to` - probably by adding methods to your `item` object, where all the conditional logic can be managed more easily than in Thymeleaf.

Comment: That way, you can define a much cleaner `#{ ... }` message (or set of messages, if there are not always both a "from" and a "to" value). Then you can externalize the data into [localized properties files](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text). The conditional logic needed in Thymeleaf would then only be needed to choose the relevant form of the message.  A [switch statement](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#switch-statements) may be a good fir for that.

Comment: Sorry if I misspoke. Yes I use internalization well.
I can't concatenate the variables in fact
For example I want to do this:
th: text = "#{message1} [internalization (From (en) Le (fr), etc] + ${item?.startDate} + #{message2} [To (en), au (Fr)] + ${item?.endDate}

Comment: In fact when $ {item? .StartTime} is null it displays null (but if for example the start and end time is null, I don't want to display # {message3} [commence le (fr), start time (in )] if the starttime variable is null ... And I can't find the syntax to conjugate internalization variables with the variables of my object AND to check if they are not null

Comment: OK - thanks for clarifying. Are you saying the Thymeleaf switch statement does not do what you need? It sounds like it should... You can use it to test which fields are null or not, and then use the relevant message format.

Comment: precisely, I found how to test if 1 variable is null, but not to check 4 and if for example the Time variables are null, do not display the message 3 and the message 4. I cannot find the right one syntax. I have to modify my question.

Comment: OK - but that comes back to the suggestion in my first comment: You can evaluate all those combinations of `null` and not-`null` in your Java object and then use that new field (a single value!) as the input into a Thymeleaf `switch` statement.

Comment: Also, just in case... You are placing your `en` messages in a separate message file from your `fr` messages, for localization support, right?

Comment: Yes I have 2 message_en.properties and message_fr.properties files

Comment: ok i will test with the switch thank you